# Sorting domain class properties with respect to another domain class properties

Tags: grails, groovy

I've two domain classes

1.**CustomerInterest.groovy**

```
static hasMany = [activities:Activity]
static belongsTo=[customer:Customer,projectProperty:ProjectProperty]

static mapping={
        activities sort:'dateCreated',order:'desc'
    }
```

2.**Activity.groovy**

```
Date dateCreated

static belongsTo = [customerInterest:CustomerInterest, employee:Employee]
```

In a controller i am doing this..

```
def customerDetails(Customer customer)
    {   

      def customerInterest=customer.customerInterests
       render view:"customerDetails",model:[customerInterest:customerInterest]
    }
```

***customerDetails.gsp***

```
<g:each in="${customerInterest}" var="ci">
    ${ci}
</g:each>
```

**

> Question: I want to sort *CustomerInterest* on property *dateCreated* of *Activity* domain.

**

Any help as soon as possible would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def customerInterest=customer.customerInterests.sort { it.activities.dateCreated }
```

Comment: thanks it has worked but what if there are no activites for a interest?

Comment: showing Customerinterest anywhere which has no activities

Comment: Then that activity is also in the list at the end.

Comment: no its not showing at the end its showing anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, you are right the interests which have no activities come after the interests which have activities but at any place..,.

Comment: any solution then i think your answer is nt totally right.

Comment: so what you want if there are no activites for a interest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55409/discussion-between-amit-sirohiya-and-user1690588).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the sort order in the mappings definition, you can use the old java `Comparable`-interface:

```
class Foo implements Comparable {

  int compareTo(anotherObject) {
    // complex logic returning -1 or 0 or 1
  }
}
```

Then you can call `listOfFoos.sort()` and it will sort it with the help of the compareTo-method.

Beware that (equals) `==` will also use this method, so ensure that (only) identical objects will return 0.

Comment: but i want to know in groovy coz i am working on it.

Comment: Indeed it is Groovy, but uses an interface from the JDK. You can model the comparator in a single class and did not have to repeat your sorting closure wherever you want to sort this.